# Using an array from a CTE in SELECT ... WHERE ... ANY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create an array of IDs once in a CTE and use it in multiple ANYs. But I'm getting stuck at the first one. Using PG 9.3

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 10)) AS a
)
SELECT 1
WHERE 2 = ANY(SELECT a FROM x)
```

What I expect is that the SELECT statement in ANY will return the previously created array. Instead I get this error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
>
> LINE 6: WHERE 2 = ANY(SELECT a FROM x)

I don't understand what the issue is because the select statement *should* return an array, and ANY *takes* an array.

I could of course not create the array in the CTE and create it on the fly in ANY every time, but I assume that would be less performant than creating it once. And I must have an array, because ANY without the array changes the query plan (when doing this on my actual table, not this small example) to something less performant.

Comment: `ANY` returns an array, all right. But is `2` really an `integer[]` or is it a plain and simple `integer`?

Comment: Why do you want to use arrays for this?  A simple subquery is the standard SQL method.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I said above, I get a different query plan with a standard subquery vs an array, and the array plan is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two forms of `ANY`. If you want to use [`ANY(array expression)`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21108)

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 10)) AS a
)

SELECT 1
FROM x
WHERE 2 = ANY(a)
```

or if you want to use [`ANY(subquery)`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME)

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS a
)

SELECT 1
WHERE 2 = ANY(SELECT a FROM x)
```

Comment: Duh! The first one is exactly what I was trying to do... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The normal SQL method for doing this does not use arrays:

```
WITH x AS (
      SELECT gs.a
      FROM generate_series(1, 10)) AS gs(a)
     )
SELECT 1
WHERE 2 IN (SELECT a FROM x);
```

Of course, you might want to be using arrays for a different reason (such as learning about arrays).  But you should at a minimum understand the SQL way to solve this problem.

Comment: I understand this way but it's less performant than using `ANY(my array)` when used on my actual data. `IN` is usually changed to `ANY` anyway, whenever I get more than a couple values in there, but the plan changes significantly when ANY is used on an array vs a table/set of rows.